# SQL Exception handling Error

Tags: sql, netbeans, exception

In my try catch :-

```
catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(dataprocess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

There is an error in dataprocess..It is underline..I got this code from internet and is there any library to import to re corrct this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really copy code from the Internet and chop it in to your program hoping it will work, unless you understand it.

Try changing dataprocess to the name of the class this code is in.

For example:

```
    public class MyClass { 
        public MyClass() { 
            try { 
               // Do sql stuff 
            } catch (SQLException ex) { 
               Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 
        } 
    }
```